# How to return class reference with generic in typescript

Tags: generics, typescript

I'm writing a type factory to spit out different type base on the string identifier, for example:

```
export class InputComponent<T> {
    constructor(public value: T) {
    }
}

export const getComponentClass = (identifier: string) => {
    switch (identifier) {
        case 'textarea':
            return Textarea;
        case 'input:number':
            // here to return InputComponent<number>
        case 'input:binary':
            return Radio;
        case 'input:string':
        default:
            // here I want to return something like InputComponent<string>
    }
}
```

Then I'll use it like (very simple example to illustrate how I would like things to happen, in the real project we use ComponentFactoryResolver to create dynamic component)

```
const classdef = getComponentClass('input:text');
const input = new classdef('hello, world');
```

Is there a way to actually do that? Or do I have to go the subclass way to have a designated class for each type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why even have the getComponentClass function when you can just make a new instance of the class with the proper type.

```
const input = new InputComponent<string>("hello world");
```

Comment: In my app, the table def is coming from the backend and shared in between apps, so I need something to determine the class type. Plus I'm creating Dynamic Component at the run time using ComponentFactoryResolver